# Best way to access a parent Activity's data

Tags: android

This is a stylistic question more than an actual "how can this be done," but the basic situation is this: I have an Activity `MyActivity` which contains a `MapFragment`, as well as a `List` of `Renderers` which are my own class that takes care of displaying some data. The `Renderers` also have `ViewPagers` which get their content views from yet another class, let's call it `ViewPagerTab`. Sometimes, something happens in some of these `ViewPagerTabs` that necessitates the update of the map in the top level `Activity`. There are, as I see it, a few approaches:

1) Both my `Renderers` and my `ViewPagerTabs` contain a reference to the context. If I cast the context as `MyActivity` I can access its map parameter.

2) By using the reference to the context, I can call `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap()` on it and get the map that way.

3) I can pass the map down from the `Activity` to the `Renderers` to the `ViewPagerTabs` as they are created so the map is accessible in each as a class variable.

4) Use a `BroadcastReceiver` in my `Activity` and send a message to it when the map needs updating from my `ViewPagerTab`.

Have I missed anything? What's the best/cleanest way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This lesson may give you some ideas:
[Communicating with other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)
Basically, the idea is to define an interface in a subunit such as a Fragment, then implement it in the parent Activity. Then, actually *call* the methods in the interface in the Fragment.

Comment: This is pretty simple and useful--I'm surprised I missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to create a class that `extends Application`. There, you can "share and declare" a number of non-context specific variables (like a glorified container, but where you don't have to create multiple instances of, or do look ups).

Requires some setup in your manifest but then all your activities can call `MyApp app = (MyApp) this.getApplication();` (or in fragments, via the onAttach activity's `.getApplication()` )

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to define a listener interface, but I've found this to be cumbersome. [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) is a really nice alternative that you should at least look into before making your decision.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit over my head but what about parcel.I think it wouldn't work because of the dynamic nature of your data however it is one way to communicate between activities.